# shtDestination based on referenced cell

Tags: excel, vba

this might be quick for someone who knows so I will appreciate any help...

I have this code:

```
  Dim shtSource As Worksheet
  Dim shtDestination As Worksheet
  Dim nSourceRow As Long, nDestRow As Long


  Set shtSource = Sheets("Forecast Opex")
  Set shtDestination = Sheets("Opex Pers Sala Admi")


    nSourceRow = 46

    For nDestRow = 2 To 97

        shtDestination.Cells(nDestRow, 3) = shtSource.Cells(nSourceRow, 2).Value 'NewForecast

        nSourceRow = nSourceRow + 1

    Next nDestRow
```

... and works just fine... the thing is that I need to make the Sheet named "Opex Pers Sala Admi" to change based on the name located in another cell (Ex. H5). The content in that cell varies depending upon certain conditions indicating the Sheet to use ad Destination.

Thank you

**UPDATE** from comment

```
Sub Update_Click() 
    Dim shtSource As Worksheet 
    Dim shtDestination As Worksheet 
    Dim nSourceRow As Long, nDestRow As Long 

    Set shtSource = Sheets("Base") 
    Set shtDestination = Sheets(Sheets("Base").Range("L21")) 

    '...
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to change its name? or its designation? or what?

Comment: What I am trying to do is extracting from one sheet (shtSource) certain data to a destination sheet (shtDestination) which continuously changes depending on certain conditions. The cell containing the name of the Sheet to be used as destination never changes and its value (the name of the sheet) is determined in another process... I am not sure if this clarifies a little better... plas advice

Comment: Please don't post code in comments.  You can edit your original post, I've done it for you this time.

Comment: You need to change `Sheets(Sheets("Base").Range("L21"))` to `Sheets(Sheets("Base").Range("L21").Value)`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

- In for loop there is no need to increment explictly the counter variable

.

```
 Sub test()

    Dim shtSource As Worksheet
    Dim shtDestination As Worksheet
    Dim nSourceRow As Long, nDestRow As Long

    Set shtSource = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtDestination = Sheets(Sheets("<sheet name>").Range("H5"))


    nSourceRow = 46

    For nDestRow = 2 To 97
        shtDestination.Cells(nDestRow, 3) = shtSource.Cells(nSourceRow, 2).Value
    Next nDestRow

End Sub
```

Comment: What makes you think `H5` is on the active sheet?  And you've broken the OPs for loop.

Comment: Thank you Santosh...
still does not work... or something is not right. I am getting Run Time Error 13... Type mismatch on:
Set shtDestination = Sheets(Range("L21"))

Comment: @chrisneilsen Broken for loop ! Nice terminology . Does that not make more sense ?

Comment: @igornachov Its always better to specify where your range H5 is else it would refer to active sheet. Please find my updated answer & also make sure the range has value which is a valid sheet name.

Comment: Chris, good question. However, the macro is activated in the active sheet and the cell H5 (actually L21 in my case) is in the same active sheet

Comment: @Santosh taking out the increment of `nSourceRow` (since the `For` increments `nDestRow`) changes the result of the loop.  Anyway, the for loop wasn't the focus of the OP, I'd suggest you take that part out of the answer.

Comment: igornachov: still, its better to avoid the vulnerability and qualify the Range reference, as Satosh's updated answer shows how to do

Comment: Guys...  I fixed the loop thing thank you... and I really appreciate your help but the shtDestination issue still does not work... 
Unless I missunderstood some of your instructions, here is the code:

Comment: Sub Update_Click()

    Dim shtSource As Worksheet
    Dim shtDestination As Worksheet
    Dim nSourceRow As Long, nDestRow As Long

    Set shtSource = Sheets("Base")
    Set shtDestination = Sheets(Sheets("Base").Range("L21"))

  nSourceRow = 46

    For nDestRow = 2 To 97
        shtDestination.Cells(nDestRow, 3) =      shtSource.Cells(nSourceRow, 2).Value
    Next nDestRow

Comment: @Santosh... excuse my ignorance but this is the first time I go into these forums and don't even know how to send a comment with a separate code... my apologies